# Executing `from abc import xyz` where does the module `abc` go?

Tags: python, module, namespaces

Question about Python internals.  If I execute  `import abc` then Python reads the module into a new namespace and binds the variable `abc` in the global namespace to point to the new namespace.

If I execute `from abc import xyz` then it reads the entire module `abc` into some new namespace and then binds the variable `xyz` in the global namespace to the same object which is bound to `xyz` in this newly created namespace where the module was read into.  At least that's my understanding.

What happens to the namespace where `abc` was read into after that?  I'm assuming it lives on somewhere, because `xyz` might access other objects in that namespace.  Can this "ghost" `abc` namespace be accessed somehow?

Also, I'm assuming that if I do

```
from abc import xyz
from abc import fgh
```

then there is only one "ghost" `abc` namespace, so that if `xyz` and `fgh` modify the same global variable in `abc`, there will only be one copy of it.  Is that correct?

Comment: Is this just out of curiosity?  There's no real reason to try to access the module "secretly" like this; if you want to access the module object, just import it normally.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, trying to understand how things work under the hood.  I do a lot of data work, thinking about moving some of this work from R to Python, so just building an understanding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The module object is stored in `sys.modules`.  So if you do `from abc import xyz`, then `sys.modules['abc']` will give you the `abc` module object.

Comment: In addition, if `xyz` depends on `abc`, it probably has its own reference to the module's globals. For example, if `xyz` is a function, `xyz.__globals__` will be `abc.__dict__`, and deleting the `sys.modules` entry won't make `xyz` lose access to that (though it will have other weird effects).